# How can I separate certain object keys into their own array?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, underscore.js

This is my first question on here. Doesn't appear to be asked elsewhere, but then again I'm not sure exactly how to phrase my question.

How can I transform an array that looks like this:

```
var message = {
    pay_key: '12345',
    'transaction[0].sender_id': 'abc',
    'transaction[0].is_primary_receiver': 'false',
    'transaction[0].id': 'def',
    'transaction[1].sender_id': 'xyz',
    'transaction[1].is_primary_receiver': 'false',
    'transaction[1].id': 'tuv',
};
```

into something like this:

```
{
pay_key : '12345',
transaction : [
    {
        sender_id : 'abc',
        is_primary_receiver : 'false',
        id : 'def'
    },
    {
        sender_id : 'xyz',
        is_primary_receiver : 'false',
        id : 'tuv'
    }
]
}
```

I have no control over the format of the first object as it comes from an external service.  I am trying to insert the message object into a MongoDB collection, but when I try to do an insert as-is, I get an error. So I'm trying to put it into the correct form.

Should I be using Underscore for this?  I've played around with _.each but can't get it to work.

Comment: @JaromandaX - "cromulent" seems an appropriate description (I must admit though that I had to look it up).  Yuk is how I'd describe it.  Something must be busted in the code upstream that is producing this because nobody would purposely want to be sending data to people that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my take..

```
var message = {
    pay_key: '12345',
    'transaction[0].sender_id': 'abc',
    'transaction[0].is_primary_receiver': 'false',
    'transaction[0].id': 'def',
    'transaction[1].sender_id': 'xyz',
    'transaction[1].is_primary_receiver': 'false',
    'transaction[1].id': 'tuv',
};

message.transaction=[];
for (var p in message) {
  var m = p.match(/^transaction\[(\d+)\]\.(.*)/);
  if (m&&m[1]&&m[2]) {
    message.transaction[m[1]]=message.transaction[m[1]]||{};
    message.transaction[m[1]][m[2]]=message[p];
    delete message[p];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic function I just whipped up

```
function makeObject(message) {
    var retObj = {},
        makePath = function (p, pos) {
            if (/\[\d+\]$/.test(p)) {
                var q = p.split(/[\[\]]/),
                    r = q[0],
                    s = q[1];
                if (!pos[r]) {
                    pos[r] = [];
                }
                return pos[r][s] = pos[r][s] || {};
            }
            return pos[p] = pos[p] || {};
        };
    for(var k in message) {
        if (message.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            if (k.indexOf('.') < 0) {
                retObj[k] = message[k];
            }
            else {
                var path = k.split('.'),
                    pos = retObj,
                    last = path.pop();
                path.forEach(function(p) {
                    pos = makePath(p, pos);
                });
                pos[last] = message[k];
            }
        }
    }
    return retObj;
}
```

It works as required, but I'm sure there's some better code to do it

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar response, so adding it anyway:

```
Object.keys(message).forEach(function(key) {
    var keySplit = key.split( /\[|\]\./g )
    if  ( keySplit.length != 1 ) {
        if ( !message.hasOwnProperty(keySplit[0]) )
            message[keySplit[0]] = [];
        message[keySplit[0]][keySplit[1]] = message[keySplit[0]][keySplit[1]]||{};
        message[keySplit[0]][keySplit[1]][keySplit[2]] = message[key];
        delete message[key];
    }
});
```